# C: memory issue with pthread_create and struct parameter

Tags: c, pthreads

It seems like I do have a memory leak, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I commented out some code so that it is a little bit more readable:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t *tid = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        parameters *p = malloc(sizeof(parameters));
        p-> something = i;
        
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *)threadFunc, p);
    }
    // some heavy main logic
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        pthread_cancel(tid[i]);
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
    free(tid);
    // End stuff
}
    
void *threadFunc(parameters *params)
{
    // take over params
    free(params);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        // do magic
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some printfs like `printf("%p\n", (void*)p)` after the  `malloc` and before the `free` and see what happens

Comment: @Jabberwocky
 i have different adresses. With this information i tried to free p in the first for after the pthread_create. The result was that the values in the threadFunc params were not available anymore

Comment: Could it be that `pthread_cancel(tid[i]);` cancels the thread before the thread calls `free(params);`

Comment: @SupportUkraine those two events are seconds apart, always

Comment: OT: Why do you want to call free in the individual thread? Why not do it in `main`

Comment: "those two events are seconds apart, always" well, nothing in the posted code shows that. A simple print statement after `free` would tell if they were all called.

Comment: "It seems like I do have a memory leak" How did you conclude that?

Comment: @SupportUkraine. How can i know that the params where used before freeing it in the main thread?

Comment: @user2292496 In `main` you first call `join` and then call `free`

Comment: @SupportUkraine: create and cancel/join are at 2 different placed, i would like to free the values when i dont need them anymore

Comment: OT: I would probably also move the `malloc` for parameters out of the loop and do a single `malloc` for an array of parameters. Remove the `free` inside the threads and do a single `free` of parameters just after `free(tid);`

Comment: " i would like to free the values when i dont need them anymore" why?

Comment: The #1 rule of `pthread_cancel()` is "never call `pthread_cancel`".  Don't do it.  Arrange for clean thread termination instead, or perhaps just leave your threads alive until you `exit()` the program.

Comment: Is `$joinAbleAttribute` copied literally from your code?  I think some C implementations do accept `$` as a valid identifier character, but that's an extension.  Did you maybe mean `&joinableAttribute`, instead?  Either way, where is it defined and what is its value?

Comment: We appreciate you presenting a simplified version of your code, but I suspect that you've simplified the problem right out of it.  What we're looking for is a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  You get an 'A' on the "minimal" part, but a "needs work" on the "reproducible example" part.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes sorry, it is &joinAbleAttribute with PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE set and destroyed after use. But your right with you other comment. 
Just use NULL, does the same

Comment: Don't cast function pointer type (`(void *)threadFunc`). Declare `void *threadFunc(void *arg)` and cast `parameters *params = (parameters *)arg`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory loss in the example provided.

Using the code from the OP and adjusted it with a few assumptions to make it compile. It does not show any memory loss using valgrind.

- Commands used to compile & memory check

```
$ gcc <source-goes-here> -lptread

$ valgrind --trace-children=yes --child-silent-after-fork=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -s <compiled-program-here>
```

- Modified code to compile (with assumptions)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// assumptions here:
typedef struct s_parameters { int something; int anotherthing[100][2]; }  parameters;
// end assumption

// added forward definition of function
void *threadFunc(parameters *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// assumptions here:
int num=5;
parameters *p=NULL;
// end assumptions

    pthread_t *tid = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        parameters *p = malloc(sizeof(parameters));
        p-> something = i;

        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *)threadFunc, p);
    }
    // some heavy main logic
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        pthread_cancel(tid[i]);
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
    free(tid);
    // End stuff
}

void *threadFunc(parameters *params)
{
    // take over params
    free(params);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        // do magic
    }
}
```

- valgrind output:

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 16 frees, 7,130 bytes allocated

 All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

 ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Good luck